How can I create more space between one group of bars and the next group of bars in a bar plot in R?
I have created a horizontal bar plot containing bars with different biological processes. These processes are assigned to a Group_ID based on their filling. The bars are already sorted according to the Group_ID. Now I would like to have a larger space between the last bar with one Group_ID and the first bar of the next Group_ID.
I have already tried geom_bar (position = "dodge"). I have also tried to insert an empty bar after a Group_ID. So far everything was without visible change
BP <- data.frame(
  ID=c('Adaptive immune response', 'Immune response', 'Exocytosis', 'Peptide transport', 'Cell-cell adhesion', 'Lipid metabolism'),
  Group_ID=c('Immune Response','Immune Response', 'Secretion And Transport', 'Secretion And Transport',    'Others', 'Others'),
  log10=c(0.8, 0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 0.3, 0.5))

BP$Group_ID <- factor(BP$Group_ID, levels = c("Immune Response", "Secretion And Transport", "Others"))
BP <- BP[order(BP_Synu_PD$Group_ID, decreasing = TRUE),]

ggplot(BP, aes(x = factor(ID, levels = unique(ID)), y = log10, fill = Group_ID)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  labs(title = "Bar Plot of signed log10(FDR)",
       x = "ID",
       y = "Signed log10(FDR)",
       fill = "Group_ID") +
  theme_few() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15))



One option would be to use facetting, i.e. facet by Group_ID then get rid of the facet look using theme() options. Additionally, as a panel border will be drawn around each facet I get rid of the panel border drawn via the theme() and instead use geom_h/vline to fake the panel border:
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(BP, aes(
  y = factor(ID, levels = unique(ID)),
  x = log10, fill = Group_ID
)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity") +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  scale_y_discrete(
    expand = expansion(add = .6)
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~Group_ID, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
  labs(
    title = "Bar Plot of signed log10(FDR)",
    y = "ID",
    x = "Signed log10(FDR)",
    fill = "Group_ID"
  ) +
  geom_hline(
    data = data.frame(
      Group_ID = c("Immune Response",  "Secretion And Transport"),
      yintercept = c(Inf, -Inf)
    ),
    aes(yintercept = yintercept)
  ) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(-Inf, Inf)) +
  ggthemes::theme_few() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
    strip.text.x = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_rect(color = NA),
    panel.spacing.y = unit(0, "pt")
  )


